# Favorite tags and up to date help

Tags: support, status-completed, help-center, tag-watching

I was reading the following page in the help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

It discusses the usage of favorite tags. Now I think this has been replaced by watching tags, but as a new user I cannot really tell.

This leads me to the question. Is the help page current? If not, how and when will it be made current?

Comment: You are correct in that [it was replaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching). They should probably update the text.

Comment: This has already been requested here (MSE): ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317114/289905).

Comment: An MSE post that mentions this issue, among others: [Update Help Center page for "finding interesting topics"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336232/335251)

Answer (score 2):

I addressed this issue as part of this request on MSE (which mentioned this as one of many updates that page needed): [Update Help Center page for "finding interesting topics"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336232/335251)

[My answer to that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381459/335251) summarizes my updates to this Help Center page:

> I've updated the [linked Help Center article](/help/interesting-topics) (located at `/help/interesting-topics`) network-wide to address all the issues you mentioned. I basically rewrote a bunch of the article (including outdated feature names and descriptions of the UI), updated the screenshots, added some clarifications to various sections, and added a new section on custom filters.
>
> While I was editing the body of the article, I also changed the title to: "**How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?**". (It was originally titled "How do I find topics I'm interested in?" – presumably referencing "interesting tags", the original name of the feature now known as [tag watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/335251).) I figured I'd avoid changing the title completely – but at least now the title more accurately reflects what this Help Center page is about.